# Add to an aspx button an css id

Tags: css, asp.net

Having the code below for a button, can I add an id to it so I can add CSS to the button?? Or I can put only a class??

```
<asp:Button ID="registerLink" runat="server" Text="Create Account">
                </asp:Button>
```

Comment: Your question is strange. Can you please edit so it will be more clear.

Your button already has ID. You can either type class="...", or in the code behind you can use registerLink.CssClass="..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In WebForms, the `ID=""` attribute of controls is transformed into something of the form `ctl0__ctl1__registerLink` (where `ctl0` and `ctl1` are the `ID=""` values of parent controls). This means the rendered `id=""` attribute is (generally) unpredictable and cannot be relied upon for styling or Javascript uses.

There are three possible solutions:

1. Use `ctrl.ClientId` to get the final rendered `id=""` attribute value, this works when you want to reference the rendered HTML from a client script on the same page, however it isn't of much use for styling unless it's an inline `<style>` element.
2. Use the `clientIDMode` setting to override how the `id=""` attribute is rendered. This requires ASP.NET 4.0 or later. You can set this in `web.config`, in your `<%@ Page` declaration, or on each element. Set it to `Static` so the value is verbatim ([with exceptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).
3. Implement your own Control Adapters that override how attributes render.
4. Ditch WebForms and use ASP.NET MVC ;)